# Combine three rows into one row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to make three cells readable like one cells but without making sum for them, I mean I have three topics have same value the example like this:

[image]

The first 20 students that they make the environmental balance they are the same who make the other two activities. I don't want to make sum for them for Power BI dashboard, because when I upload them to Power BI they will 6o students who make these activities but actually they are 20

Comment: hi welcome to Super User, your question is very confusing, can you try and edit it to make more sense ?

Comment: Please provide **usable** examples of your original data (with confidential portions changed); your existing code; your desired output, and the logic you are using to derive the output.  On the surface, it seems you could `Group` in Power Query using a Text Aggregation method, but your question is to unclear to provide a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that each student has three rows (one for each activity), and you want to combine so that it is one row per student.

You have a few options. You can either (A) make new columns (activity 1, activity 2, activity 3) or (B) join the activities into one cell as a comma separated text list e.g. `=A1 & ", " & A2 & ", " & A3`.

Firstly I will assume you have a name column. If the list is not sorted, use *Home > Sort & Filter* to sort all the data according to the name column so that every 4th row is a new student (i.e. rows 2 to 4 must be grouped, then 5 to 7, then 8 to 10 etc).

Lets say you want option (A). Create columns for activity 1, activity 2, activity 3 and put these formula in each (assuming activity is in column A):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,3) = 0, A2, "")
=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,3) = 0, A3, "")
=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,3) = 0, A4, "")
```

Now add a filter, and filter column "activity 1" by unchecking "(Blanks)".

If you plan to pull this table into Power BI, you might want to copy and paste the filtered data to a new sheet.

Comment: For option (B) use something like this `=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,3) = 0, A2&", "&A3&", "&A4, "")`

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, it's hard to tell what you're asking without further clarification and perhaps some examples of input and output.

I believe what you're looking for is SUMPRODUCT() and the double unary operator.  Here's a pretty full explanation: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/

To dumb down how to use SUMPRODUCT() and the double unary operator: you set up a formula that answers a bunch of things true (1) or false (0).  If anything is false, when you multiply all those 1's and 0's together, the product will be zero.  And, if nothing is false, the product will be one.  So, you set up all your conditions, and you also include a value that doesn't get reduced to true or false, that is the thing or things you actually want to sum.

This back and forth I had a long time ago explains it even more simply:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/532101-is-there-a-function-countif-that-operates-like-sumif.html